# Unknown configuration variable "protocol" Error mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am configure mosquitto for mqtt with **tcp** and **websocket**. using steps of below link,

http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2015/05/18/six-steps-to-install-mosquitto-1-4-2-with-websockets-on-debian-wheezy/comment-page-1/

tcp is working good.

but websocket is not working.

I add below lines to **mosquitto.conf**,

```
port 1883
listener 9001
protocol websockets**
```

I comment **protocol websockets** line from mosquitto.conf file, the mosquitto is working good.Otherwise i got error  **Unknown configuration variable "protocol"**.
I want know if any certificate file need to execute this.
Please help me out........

Answer (score 1):

This error will only occur if you have used a version of mosquitto prior to 1.4. If you have installed 1.4.x but not compiled with websockets support, you will receive the error

```
Error: Websockets support not available.
```

Check what version you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
    yum install c-ares-devel libuuid-devel openssl-devel -y

    # if you don't want to install dependencies, open config.mk,
    # modify WITH_TLS:=no、WITH_TLS_PSK:=no、WITH_UUID:=no、WITH_SRV:=no

    # download mosquitto 1.4.7
    wget http://mosquitto.org/files/source/mosquitto-1.4.7.tar.gz
    tar xzf mosquitto-1.4.7.tar.gz

    # download libwebsocket
    wget http://git.libwebsockets.org/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/snapshot/libwebsockets-1.6.0-chrome48-firefox42.tar.gz

    # compile and install libwebsocket
    cd libwebsockets-1.6.0-chrome48-firefox42
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake .. -DLIB_SUFFIX=64
    sudo make install
    ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libwebsockets.so.6 /lib64/libwebsockets.so.6
    # compile end

    # compile mosquitto
    cd ../../mosquitto-1.4.7
    make
    # compile end

    # vim mosquitto.conf
    # line 275 add listener 8000
    # line 295 add protocol websockets

    # add mosquitto user
    groupadd mosquitto
    useradd -s /sbin/nologin mosquitto -g mosquitto -d /var/lib/mosquitto

    # make sure kill any program use 1883 and 8000
    src/mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf
```

Ubuntu

```
    apt-get install cmake git zlib1g.dev libssl-dev

    cd libwebsockets-1.6.0-chrome48-firefox42
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake .. -DLIB_SUFFIX=64
    sudo make install

    ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libwebsockets.so.6 /lib/libwebsockets.so.6

    cd mosquitto-1.4.7
    make

    # line 136 uncomment port 1883
    # line 275 listener 8000
    # line 295 protocol websockets
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS version all above steps are worked,but while compile mosquitto.conf i got error unknown configuration protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am tried above ubuntu steps, still got the same error. any certificate files are need or any support files ?.

Comment: rndserver@rndserver:~/mosquitto-1.4.7$ sudo mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf
Error: Websockets support not available.
Error found at mosquitto.conf:139.
Error: Unable to open configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you compiled mosquitto with websocket ??

You should install libwebsocket first, and recompile mosquitto with in WITH_WEBSOCKETS:=yes

Comment: I am installing mosquitto 1.4.7. and i change WITH_WEBSOCKETS:=yes in config.mk file.